# Vectorization of a complex object python

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, vectorization

The following code is used to apply a function across all the members of an object "nspace". The nspace contains a list of more nspaces, with a dimension variable reduced by 1. An nspace with dimension=1 is a list of "None"s. Is it possible to vectorize this function?

```
def __call__(self, func):
        if self.dimension == 1:
            for i in range(self.size):
                self.list[i,] = func(self.list[i,])
        else:
            for i in self.list:
                i(func)
```

nspace's structure:

```
nspace(3,3)=[nspace(2,3), nspace(2,3), nspace(2,3)]
nspace(2,3)=[nspace(1,3), nspace(1,3), nspace(1,3)]
nspace(1,3)=[None, None, None]

nspace(2,4)=[nspace(1,4), nspace(1,4), nspace(1,4), nspace(1,4)]
```

Comment: can you define nspace? is it a linear space?

Comment: nspace is technically an n-dimensional list. It contains a list within it that contains more nspace objects that are one dimension lower.